# ExpressJS Google Api response error Required parameter: q

Tags: express, xmlhttprequest, google-books

I have an ExpressJS and I want to retrieve data from the Google Books api. I have created the following test request aimed at hitting https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0743273567:

```
const express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
const auth = require('../middlewares/authenticate');
const User = require('../models/User');
const Book = require('../models/Book');

let router = express.Router();

...

//test get books api example
router.get('/google', async (req, res, next) => {
  request({
    uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes',
    qs: {
      api_key: process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY,
      query: 'isbn:9781440346026'
    }
  }).pipe(res);
});
```

Instead of information about the book, the request returns:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "message": "Required parameter: q",
        "locationType": "parameter",
        "location": "q"
      }
    ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Required parameter: q"
  }
}
```

Comment: In your request you have the property set to `query`.  You should change this to be just the value `q`, and that would return results.

Comment: That worked! Thanks. If you formulate as an answer, I will accept.

Comment: I've posted as an answer to better illustrate

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that will return a response using the request client when visiting http://localhost:3000/google.  Note that I'm passing the value `q` instead of `query` in the qs object.

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/google', (req, res) => {
  request({
    uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes',
    qs: {
      q: 'isbn:9781440346026'
    }
  }).pipe(res);
});

app.listen(port);
```